# Configue UART WiFi module

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, network-adapter, wpa2-psk

I recently bought a UART WiFi module ( [this one](http://www.elechouse.com/elechouse/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=90_186&products_id=1007) ) and configured it with right SSID but wrong password( and I don't know what it is ). The problem is that I can't reset this module to its manufacture settings and I can't connect to this module via serial port to configure it with some wire or cable. But I'm sure that my module is trying to connect my access point but with wrong network key ( because in logs of my access point I can see my module that trying to connect but it can't )

So, I wonder to know is there any way to create or configure a network (using some access point or something else) based on WPA2 Personal security that accepts any WPA2-PSK passwords ? Or is there any other solution for this problem ? If no, is there anyway to see what password this module using to connect to that network ? ( If yes, then I can change password of my network to that password and access to this module's admin panel )

I tried create an open network ( without any security key ) but my module just searches for WPA2 based networks ( I think ).

Comment: I might have misunderstood this, but if you forgot a password and it is sending out information, why not try to crack that password? You must have a general idea of what the password was, which would greatly narrow down the time. If I completely misunderstood this question, I apologize, that is why this isn't an answer =p

Comment: Thanks @ekaj but i don't forget my ap password. I just can't reconfigure my wifi module because it can't connect to my desired network with network key it provides to AP. And i can't change my module's network key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question as posted in the title is not worth answering IMO, because I suspect it's one roundabout attempt to solve the root problem that just begets more unsolved problems.

> I can't connect to this module via serial port to configure ...

Can you connect to this module through its serial port from a PC?

If you cannot communicate with this module over its serial port, then doesn't that defeat the purpose of this module, and render it useless?

The user manual for that module states

> 2.3.3 Command Mode of Serial
>
> Module also provides the **command mode** based on serial control, which is different from auto-work mode, this
>   mode provides the user with sufficient flexibility, and meet users’
>   specific needs of different applications.  In this mode, the module
>   works according to user command through the serial, **user can control
>   the module** completely with the command, including **modifying
>   parameters**, controling networking, controling TCP/IP connection and
>   data transmission.

Seems like the solution to the **root problem** involves figuring out (i.e. reading the manual on) how to activate this **command mode** through the module's serial port.  Some familiarity with the structure of the AT command format (based on the old Hayes dial-up modem command set) would help to understand the sparse manual.  Perhaps the vendor can supply a GUI or command line interface for the serial port (there are numerous screen captures of a *UART-WIFI Configuration* program that seems distinct from the web interface); otherwise you can write your own interface program or else (as last resort) use a **terminal emulator** (e.g. *putty* or *teraterm* or *Hyperterminal*(yuck), or minicom for linux) to manually type the AT commands.

> Or is there any other solution for this problem ?

After skimming the user manual, the simple answer is that you need to download and install the "Wifi software", which is the *UART-WIFI Configuration* program.  That appears to be a Windows GUI program that connects to the module through the serial port (ref ***5.1.2.1 Management through serial connection***), and allow module configuration changes, including a restore to factory settings.

**Addendum**

Further review of the user manual indicates that this module has a peculiar implementation of the Hayes AT command set.  In particular:

- Instead of "AT" commands, it is really "AT+" commands.  The null command does require the plus character.  All commands begin with the three characters "AT+".
- The default escape time is 2 seconds, not the more common 1 second.  In order to escape (data) transmission mode, no data or text can be sent to the serial port for 2 seconds, then three "+" (plus) characters must be sent, and then no data or text for 2 seconds.  The module should then respond with the "+OK" command prompt.

Comment: Really thanks for this great answer, i tried gui application at the first but it did not work. I think that I must search for command mode state of this module. I'll try it out soon and let you know dear sawdust. AGAIN, many thanks.

Comment: @swadust: if I send three +++ via serial port (terminal) module responds nothing. I tested it many times. I tested my USB-TTL module with my microcontroller and it works pretty well. What's the problem ?

Comment: Be sure your are sending nothing for 2 seconds, then the "+++" quickly, and then nothing again.  If no response, then you have to troubleshoot the serial port connection: verify settings for baud rate, number of data and stop bits, parity.  Maybe connect an oscilloscope and look for chars on the Tx & Rx pins on the module.  But your comment *"USB-TTL module ... works pretty well"* is confusing.  Is the serial port connection doing something?  Are you just typing the plusses too slow?

Comment: I create a circuit with 2x16 LED using Atmega32 and connect RX and TX of my micro to my USB-TTL converter and connect that module to my computer. When I send a character to via hyper terminal (or AVRCodeVision's terminal) it appears in my 2x16 LED (I mean my USB-TTL module works well). I'll send that characters right after 2 seconds and let you know the results in some minutes.

Comment: BTW,its not "USB to TTL Converter" ...Its "USB to Serial Converter with TTL Output" ... but its not giving 3.3 volt output (4.7 instead) ... I'll try MAX232 and let you know.

Comment: *"USB to TTL Converter"* I think I understand what that adapter is.  It's like these FTDI products  http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/Cables/USBTTLSerial.htm .

Comment: problem solved by sending three + as a text file. Thanks for your great answer (again)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately for you, WPA2-PSK authentication is bi-directional, meaning that both the client and the AP have to know the same key or the authentication fails. If the AP doesn't know the same key as the client, the math just doesn't work out, and no communication is possible. So there's no way to do what you're asking.

**Update for clarity:** The AP doesn't get a choice to accept or not accept the WPA2-PSK the client has. The AP **must** already know the exact same PSK as the client, because if it doesn't, there's no way to for the AP to transmit packets that the client will understand. The client will expect the frames to be encrypted using a key derived from the PSK and the authentication handshake, and will ignore all unencrypted frames. If the AP doesn't know the key the client expects, it will not be able to derive an encryption key that the client will accept.

Comment: I think you are right, but is there any way to reconfigure AP to accept  any WPA2-PSK network key?

Comment: @Michel I updated my Answer to make it more clear. The way the crypto works, it is mathematically impossible to do what you're asking. Clients can't understand APs that don't know the same PSK, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 2):

In case its of any use to anyone else using these boards...

I initially had issues with some UART Wifi boards (marketed as TLG10UA03), because they wouldn't communicate via RS232 at all, and I suspected that either I'd damaged them by applying the wrong RS232 voltage or they were faulty.

However I found I was able to login on wifi with username  admin and password 000000
and this revealed that the modules were working, but that the data rate had been set to 9600 despite all the documentation that I'd previously seen, specifying that the data rate was 115200.

However initially at 9600 the board would not communicate with the PC "UART-WIFI Configuration" program (UART-WIFI.exe)

But using the "Hercules SETUP utility by HW-group.com", which was a download on one of the many sites for the UART-Wifi, I used the "Serial" (tab) and selected my USB to RS232 TTL board (dongle), and set the data rate to 9600N81.
Then used the "send" feature at the bottom of the serial screen (tab), to send +++

The board the responded with OK

I was then able to use the UART-WIFI.exe, making sure to set the data rate to 9600N81, as the default on this program seems to be 115200.
I presume that the module must have been in a different mode, as the +++ switched it into a mode that can communicate with the UART-WIFI.exe
There may also be a way to enter this mode using the hardware pins on the board, however I've not investigated this yet.

However, I do get one error message of "command not supported", but this doesn't seem to stop any of the UART-WIFI.exe functionality from working.

NB.I've yet to analyze which command that UART-WIFI.exe sends, is not supported by my board.

I'm hoping to write my own exe to communicate with the board when I get chance, which will remove the need for use of a separate terminal program to put the module into the correct mode.

Answer (score 1):

Module has no obvious ROM on it. I'd guess that with reset attempts you cleared MAC address and you need to program it back.

Comment: no it have some internal flash memory as described in its datasheet.

Comment: OK, AP is not programmed permanently. You need to feed MAC and channel config back to internal flash rom.

Comment: @ZaB - *Module has no obvious ROM on it* : obviously you would be surprised at the level of integration in current microcontrollers.  For example the are many variations of SoC (system on a chip) about 1 to 4 square cm in size with a 16- or 32-bit processor (e.g. ARM 7), tens of KB RAM, hundreds of KB flash and an assortment of peripherals such as timers, AtoD converters, serial ports, USB, Ethernet and even maybe a LCD interface at a quantity price of a few dollars per chip.

Comment: WiFi module is a "network card". if it has internal microcode loaded it knows how to handle associate and send commands and it's own mac address etc. it is more like 8KB of ROM, not a SoC or so.

Comment: @ZaB - First you write that there's "no obvious ROM".  Now it's "8KB of ROM".  Huh?  This module can process AT commands received on its serial port.  It has a built-in web server accessible through its 802.11 interface.  That functionality requires an onboard processor.  The photo shows a square IC, which looks like the BGA packaging used by some SoCs.  *Ergo*, this module uses a SoC.  I've used and developed similar embedded products as this module, and am acquainted (if not familiar) with the designs of these types of modules.  SoCs are in widespread use.

Comment: oops i di not scroll to the text:
    Connect wifi module with PC via USB-TTL module. Start wifi software to find the device. Input all the information needed to configure the wifi module.

Answer (score 1):

According to my experience, the module can be restored to its original factory state by doing this:

- Be sure the module accepts AT+ commands by sending `+++` and receiving `+OK`. If not, keep shorting pins 2 and 5 while restarting the module, to force command mode.
- With the module in command mode, send `AT+RSTF` to reset the module to factory settings. The module should reply with `+OK`.

Now you can make changes to the configuration, and then you can save your changes in internal flash (`AT+PMTF`), and reset the module again (`AT+Z`).